# How do you delete rows in a Delta table using SQL?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I am using Databricks. In my notebook, I have a table (Delta table) and I want to delete all rows where the topic is 'CICD' from my table. I want to use SQL to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM databasename.my_bronze_table WHERE Topic == 'CICD'
```

After running the above code, it displayed the number of rows affected.